# Imprimir el número que más se repite en un arreglo en C

Tags: array, c, contador

Debo recibir el tamaño de un arreglo, seguido de los números del arreglo, y debo imprimir el número que se repite más dentro de ese arreglo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(){

    int i,n, j, contador;
    
        scanf("%d",&n);
    int arreglo[n];
        
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &arreglo[i]);
  }
    
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            contador=0;
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
                if(arreglo[i]==arreglo[j])
                contador++; 
        
                }
        
        }
```

En el ejemplo las entradas son las siguientes:

> 6
>
> 3 4 4 5 1 7

Y la salida solo debe ser:

> 4

Intenté así pero es muy lento, y aparte no sé cómo imprimir el número.

Comment: puede mostrar un mensaje con printf(formato, variable);, ejemplo: printf("El numero es: %d", num);  %d, significa que la variable 'num' se mostrará de forma decimal(como un numero entero)

Comment: No deberías aceptar cambios que rompen tu código ... han añadido una llave de más (que se ha inventado) y que hace que tu código no compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir algo se utiliza **printf();**, como lo mencioné en el comentario de la publicación, puedes ver mas detalles en [printf](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf). el desarrollo de la lógica es importante, y te recomiendo practicar con otros ejercicios, en tu código solo falta implementarla un poco mas, te explicaré con el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    //int i;                                // MALA PRACTICA
    int n, aux = 0, mas_veces;
    int contador;
    
    printf("Cantidad de numeros para el arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    int arreglo[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){                 // Declarar la variable 'i' en el mismo 'for'
        scanf("%d", &arreglo[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        
        contador = 0;                       // Restablecer el contador para proceder a contar la cantidad de veces del siguiente numero
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            
            if(arreglo[j] == arreglo[i]){   // Comparar un elemento selecionado del arreglo con los demas elementos
                contador++;                 // aumentar el contador en caso de encontrar el elemento selecionado 
            }
        }
        
        if(contador > aux){                 // CAMBIO
            mas_veces = arreglo[i];         // Establecer mas_veces como el elemento del arreglo, en la vuelta que va
            aux = contador;
        }
    }
    printf("\nEl numero que mas se repite es: %d", mas_veces);
    return 0;
}
```

**MALA PRACTICA:**

Se considera de mala practica declarar variables que se utilizarán para el recorrido del **for**, afuera de este, es conveniente declararlas en el mismo **for**, ejemplo: for(int i=0; i<n; i++), de esta manera, cunado se vaya a crear otro **for**, se pueda manipular nuevamente desde 0, se ahorran líneas de código y en algunos casos se hace mas entendible. **Nota:** La variable que declares en ese espacio, dejara de tener un valor, una vez ya salgas del bucle.

**CAMBIO:**

En la primera vuelta, **aux** va a valer 0, así que si o si, el que se repite mas veces por ahora será el primer elemento, luego **aux** obtiene el valor del contador, supongamos que con el primer elemento se contaron 2 repeticiones, en caso de que la segunda vuelta, solo cuente que hay una sola repetición del segundo elemento, contador valdría 1, **aux** vale 2, así que no se cumple la condición, y el primer elemento por ahora seguiría siendo el que mas se repite, si en la tercera, el tercer elemento se repite 3 veces, ahora **contador** valdría 3, se cumple la condición, y el que mas veces se repite por ahora seria ese mismo elemento(el tercero), así comprobando el resto de números del arreglo.

Si tienes alguna duda, escríbela en un comentario.